# creating canvas and elements using jquery

Tags: jquery, easeljs

I'm creating elements in canvas using jQuery and using the help of easeljs for the canvas.
So I made more than one canvas. In which I created elements in it (buttons, image ,etc). Since I'm using jQuery I give each elements a variable name.

The problem occurred when I click the button in the first canvas, it affected the elements in the last canvas. Where what I want was each button effects elements in its own canvas. I realized the problem is in the variable name declaration, since all elements ended up having the same name. So how do I fix this? I'm trying to give each elements different name, but it's not en effective way. Since the naming would be a bundle.

Edit:

Well, the jquery function is called timeline, so I apply it like this:

```
$('#object1').timeline();
$('#object2').timeline();
```

The object is the name of the canvas.

In the jquery the script would be similar like this:

```
stage = new createjs.Stage('canvas_name');
mC = new createjs.Container();
stage.addChild(mC);
button = new createjs.Shape();
stage.addChild(button);
```

Now the buttons should only effect the mC in each of its own canvas. But since the variable naming is the same in each canvas, so it effects the ones in the last canvas only.

Hope this makes it clear a bit.

The button and effects:

```
scrollPos = 0;
for(a=0; a<2; a++) {
    scrollC2[a] = new createjs.Container();
    scrollC2[a].id = a;
    scrollC2[a].mouseChildren = false;
    scrollC2[a].on('click', function(e) {
        if(e.target.id == 0) {
            if(scrollPos <= 0) {

            }else {
                scrollPos--;
            }
        }else if(e.target.id == 1) {
            if(scrollPos >= 6) {

            }else {
                scrollPos++;    
            }
        }
        mC.x = -scrollPos * 500; //500 is the canvas width
        canvas.update();
    })
}
```

So if the button is clicked, the mC move to the left or right depending on which button is clicked

Comment: what did you use for the naming for each element in each canvas, and what the selector and jQuery that you use for buttons that will affect their own canvas. jsfiddle link would be helpful.

Comment: @Kyojimaru, i edited my questions, hope it helps

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I mean the jQuery for the button on click event and the result of the html

Comment: @meagar sorry, i'll fix it

Answer (score 0):

So, in most jquery plugins you have to write the below line for beginning right?

```
return this.each(function()
```

And then i put these lines

```
var _this = this;
```

Then i give avery variable names using _this

```
_this.mC = new createjs.Container();
_this.mShape = new createjs.Shape();
etc;
```

And so all functions and handler only effect the element that you put jquery plugin in.